# Script using the wrong python version

Tags: mac, python

When I type python on the terminal, I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:32:06) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

but  when i run a python script i got the following:

```
WARNING: python-gevent not installed. `curl -k -L http://git.io/I9B7RQ|sh`
------------------------------------------------------
GoAgent Version    : 2.1.9 (python/2.7.2 gevent/None pyopenssl/0.13)
Listen Address     : 127.0.0.1:8087
GAE Mode           : https
GAE Profile        : google_hk
GAE APPID          : goagent
Pac Server         : http://127.0.0.1:8086/proxy.pac
------------------------------------------------------
```

What should I configure to let the script using the right version python, cause when I try to install gevent, it told I already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this.

First, you can call the script explicitly, using the python you want.  To determine which python bin is being used, you can type:

```
which python
```

This will give you the full path to the python being used when you type `python` at the command line.

In any case, you can just type:

```
python script_name_here
```

Or you can use the full path to your python and do the same.

The second way is to edit your script, and edit the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to point to the python returned by `which python`.  In other words, edit the script you're running and change the first line to something like:

```
#!/path/to/python2.7.3
```